# How to display the raw bits composing a file as a bitmap image?

Tags: c#, file, bmp

I want to display a file (e.g. a MIDI file) as a bitmap by turning the file into a byte array and constructing a bitmap from the bytes.

Comment: Convert an audio-file to an image? It´s completely unclear to me what you want to achieve. But anyway you should provide what you´ve tried already, not just expecting us to do your work, which is **thinking, trying out, thinking again**.

Comment: Yes, it's all just bytes there's no reason you can't convert almost any file in to an image.

Comment: I wrote the answer to this because it was suggested for me to do so when this question was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860580/is-there-a-way-i-can-convert-a-midi-file-into-a-bitmap-image-using-c

Comment: Well, to quote the comments to the mentioned question: "to write your question in as focused a way as possible, to lower the aforementioned possibility of numerous low-quality answers". Your question is as unclear as the closed one.

Comment: What is unclear? I can't write this anymore clearly it does what is says on the tin

Comment: A proper question for "how to achieve this" usually includes "this is my current code, but it fails my expectations for the following reasons...". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192415/discussion-between-adaraider-and-himbrombeere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do the following:

```
        public void Convert()
        {
            string filePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\sample.mid";
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            int pixelCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(bytes.Count() / 4.0);
            double width = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(pixelCount));
            double height = Math.Ceiling(pixelCount / width);
            string outputPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\sample.bmp";
            SaveAsBmp((int)width, (int)height, bytes, outputPath);
        }

        public void SaveAsBmp(int width, int height, byte[] argbData, string path)
        {
            using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
            {
                BitmapData data = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, img.PixelFormat);
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(argbData, width * y, data.Scan0 + data.Stride * y, width * 4);
                }
                img.UnlockBits(data);
                img.Save(path, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
        }
```

The following was obtained from the sample MIDI provided from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MIDI_sample.mid?qsrc=3044

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with a midi file. It will 'work' with any binary file. So the question title sems to be quite misleading.. I would have expected you want to display the notes, but the raw bytes have no more to do with music than the raw bytes of a jpg with an image.

Comment: Yes it would, I don't see how that makes the answer wrong?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit out the MIDI reference from the question. Now question and answer both are aligned and make sense. (A little..;-) - Feel free to accept your answer, if you are happy with its solution. If you want something different feel free to explain..!

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you taking the time to help improve the question and answer

Comment: Unfortunately you can't accept your own answer for at least 2 days

Comment: Well one can if one does it immediately; but what are 2 days in the face of eternitiy ;-)